# Run ADB Shell and then interact with console app in Python

Tags: python, android, python-3.x

I have a situation where I need to run the `adb shell` command which takes me to the root access of my device.

Then I run the interactive console app against my device using this command: `/oem/console --no-logging`.

The command returns this output:

- Console Process: connecting to application...
- Console Process: connected to application...

After this, I need to PRESS ENTER so that the console accepts events (The arrow cursor is ready to accept invoke events). This console app takes certain events that I can simulate my device's behavior. For example:

1. `invoke put.device.into.charge 1`
2. `invoke call.cell.hangup 1`
3. `invoke xyz`

So my question is, how do I one-by-one enter these commands into this console app and wait a couple of seconds after each command?

This is the code I have so far:

```
def run_adb_shell_command(command, return_process=False):
    """Run an ADB shell command."""
    cmd = command.split()
    process = Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    if return_process:
        return process



def send_command_to_console_app(command, process):
    """SEND Commands to Console App."""
    new_line = '\n'.encode()
    # encoded_command = str(command).encode()
    s0 = command
    s1 = 'event 1'
    s2 = 'event 2'
    s3 = 'event 3'
    concat_query = "{}\n".format(s0)

    process.communicate(input=concat_query.encode('utf-8'))[0]
    process.kill()
```

The problem is that when `communicate()` function is called for one of the events it just hangs up and never finishes so that I can run the next event.

What is the best approach for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, after a couple of days of research, I found a solution from this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/56051270/4911426. I had to use an asynchronous subprocess for chaining different commands together.

Comment: Can you post your findings?